# IOS 7 DateCell example with a XIB

Tags: ios, datepicker, xib

I have looked through Apple's [DateCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html) example, unfortunately as all other examples I found it is based on a storyboard. I am trying to create a simple TableViewController with two cells, one for showing the selected date and another for showing a date picker.The Controller will be connected to a bigger app which does not use storyboards. Can somebody write a short guidelines how to recreate the TableView from Apple's example as a XIB and a few sentences regarding the implementation?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After making a sufficient research on the topic, I managed to build a solution out of two separate tutorials.

My main problem were the dynamic prototype cells used in the storyboard example provided by Apple. Therefore I created a customised cell with UIDatePicker inside. I used [this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/) tutorial to customise the cell xib file according to my needs and then used it in the UITableView.

Afterwards I followed [this](http://masteringios.com/blog/2013/10/31/ios-7-in-line-uidatepicker/1/) tutorial, only instead of a storyboard I created a UITableViewController and used the custom cell with UIDatePicker inside. This example seemed much easier to follow than the sample code provided by Apple.

I didn't encounter any other problems on the way, but if you have any questions I would gladly try to answer. I am still quite new to iOS and Objective-C, so maybe three is a better and easier solution out there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create two custom cells (one for selected date, second for picker), which both are subclasses of `UITableViewCell`. 
You also need to create two xib files for them. Then change the class of xib to our custom class and connect outlets. Next import that classes to your `UITableViewController`. In method `viewDidLoad` write something:

```
UINib *customNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomNibName" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:customNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCellIdentifier"];
```

After that you can use your cells in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method:

```
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```